# Cannot set map's div height for openlayers map

Tags: openlayers

This code make the map's div width max but height to 0 (the % value doesn't matter, it's always 0)

```
<div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>
```

This works, as it sets the map's div to a fixed size, but is obviously not what I want.

```
<div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"></div>
```

Has someone experienced this? Anyone a suggestion on how to fix this?

I'm also using jquery(-mobile)

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is my fix:

```
function fixContentHeight(){
    var viewHeight = $(window).height();
    var header = $("div[data-role='header']:visible:visible");
    var navbar = $("div[data-role='navbar']:visible:visible");
    var content = $("div[data-role='content']:visible:visible");
    var contentHeight = viewHeight - header.outerHeight() - navbar.outerHeight();
    content.height(contentHeight);
    map.updateSize();
}
```

Comment: basically, change the size of #map then call the bloody map.updateSize();

Answer (score 5):

You need to give 100% height to HTML and Body:

```
html, body {
height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: But the map div itself still needs real px values and not percentages afaik.

Comment: This worked for me, setting also #map {width:100%; height:100%;}

Answer (score 2):

in case you use jquery, this works perfectly to 'stretch' your map to the container div holding it, notmatter what your css has set for the map :

```
   $(window).resize(function () {
      //$('#log').append('<div>Handler for .resize() called.</div>');
         var canvasheight=$('#map').parent().css('height');
         var canvaswidth=$('#map').parent().css('width');

         $('#map').css("height", canvasheight);
         $('#map').css("width", canvaswidth);

   });
```

You would call this early btw, ideally in a *$(document).ready(function(){ /* here */ }* block.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this topic because I wanted to set the map height in an ionic tab ([ionicframework](http://ionicframework.com/)) to 100%. Even though this was not the original question maybe others run into this topic with the same issue. Additionally to the previous suggestions you have to set the height of the class .scroll to 100%:

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.scroll {
    height: 100%;
}

#map {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: For the ones with same problem as above, just set your <ion-content scroll="false"> and no more CSS is needed

Answer (score -1):

I've resolved this for my use-case by adding:

```
setInterval(function(){map.updateSize();}, 500);
```

Update: This is no loner what I do under OpenLayers 3. I did this while using OpenLayers 2. I'm not saying it's pretty, but it was good enough for what I needed.

Comment: That's pretty wasteful though because you run this code every 500ms. This is not really what you want to do. See my or Glenn's answer for a more cleaner way

Comment: it does not set the size of the map, map gets distorter.

Comment: @olga Maybe you're using OL3? My approach worked at all for OL2.