# bootstrap column height 100 of content with openlayers map

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, openlayers-3

I am using bootstrap design features for my application. I have an openlayers map in my main cotent.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="well">
      Header
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="well">
        <h2>
            Sidebar
        </h2>
        <ul>
          <li>menu item 1</li>
          <li>menu item 2</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8 fill">
      <div class="map" id="map"> </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and javascript code is like this:

```
var map = new ol.Map({
  target: "map",
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM()
    })
  ],
   view: new ol.View({
       center: [0, 0],
       zoom: 2
   })
})
```

[Working demo is here](https://jsfiddle.net/barteloma/L1yLpvz2/4/)

I want to set map height to fill column(`<div class="col-sm-8 fill">`) of page.
But it does not fill 100%.

Answer (score 3):

As explained in this [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12887506/cannot-set-maps-div-height-for-openlayers-map), you need to make the map fixed position or dynamically set the height.

You could also use 100vh..

```
.map {height:100vh; width: 100%;}
```

http://codeply.com/go/wpuEToiHM4

Answer (score 0):

sofar I understand your question, I'd make just a class .fill inside my css. and set the height to 100%

.map {

height: 100%;

}